# Why doesn't viewport width work for borders?

Tags: css

I want to fit the child element perfectly inside its parent. 
The correct height and width for the child seemed to be 14vw. I got this number by subtracting 2vw (the border amount from the parent and child) from 16vw, which is the parent's width and height. Yet when I resize my browser, there is a noticeable gap between the child's bottom border, and the parent. There is also a smaller gap between the right borders.

It seems that viewport width isn't behaving as I expected it to. Any explanation as to why this is the case?

I also noticed that when I inspect the border element in the developer tools, it is always an integer. If viewport width is 1% of the browser width, it seems that this should not be the case.

```css
body {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  border: 1vw solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.child {
  width: 14vw;
  height: 14vw;
  position: relative;
  border: 1vw solid #654321;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='child'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you include the viewport in the metas of the html headers?

Comment: Pixel rounding I would imagine...after all...what does *half a pixel* look like?

Comment: Actually this page says that pixels don't necessary represent screen pixels: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, floating point sizes are correct. You can see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length or https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-values-20050726/. It says:

> Values of the  CSS data type can be interpolated in order to allow animations. In that case they are interpolated as real, floating-point, numbers. The interpolation happens on the calculated value. The speed of the interpolation is determined by the timing function associated with the animation.

I guess your situation happens because browser can't render for example `0.5px` border width so it always has to work with rounded integer border values.

You can actually fix this by letting the internal `.child` fill the entire space and including its own border size to its dimensions:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/dsLpa7kg/